# (AJAX/PHP) Why is my POST request not working in this brief example?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "pants.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var slot = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
xhr.send("name=Sarah");
```

I am sending "name=Sarah" to testpage.php via POST, and when I get a response, I'm doing to display it on my page.

And here's pants.php:

`echo $_POST['name'];`

So I should just be displaying "Sarah" on the page. But instead, I get the error ": Undefined index: name". I can't seem to understand why this is...

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/5HHSv/. But PHP might really require content type headers, I don't know.

Comment: I would also suggest to start using the [Developer Tool Bar](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to help debug AJAX requests. If you look on the Network/Net tabs it will tell you if you successfully POSTed values and if so, what endpoint, the payload, how much time it took etc.

Comment: @FelixKling — When I run that test, I get a `Content-Type: text/plain` request header, which PHP (correctly) won't parse as form data.

Comment: @Quentin: OK, that makes sense. I thought it might still try to parse the payload as form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

This header is mandatory for POST requests

Comment: Could you cite a source that supports your claim?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I didn't know about that, I learnt something.

Comment: The header is included by default, just with a different value (one that doesn't tell PHP you've encoded it as form data).

Comment: Ok, it's not mandatory "de jure", but it's mandatory "de facto". `Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD treat it as type "application/octet-stream"`. (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1)